# In file './docker-compose.yml', services 'image' must be a mapping not a string

Tags: docker-compose

```yaml
wordpress:
  image: wordpress
  links:
    - wordpress_db:mysql
  ports:
    - 8080:80
wordpress_db:
  image: mariadb
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: edureka
phpmyadmin:
  image: corbinu/docker-phpmyadmin
  links:
    - wordpress_db:mysql
  ports:
    - 8181:80
  environment:
    MYSQL_USERNAME: root
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: edureka
```

Comment: I tried to format your yaml properly, but I believe by doing so I removed the actual problem. Please insert your actual yaml file contents in the same way, so it's formatted properly. If your error message contains a line number, please add that as well.

Comment: Error while fetching server API version: ('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))

Comment: Please provide the actual content of your docker-compose.yml

Comment: ok. it's fine now. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Minimal docker-compose.yaml file:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  web:
    image: nginx:alpine
    ports:
     - 80:80
```

For run: docker compose up

For run in background: docker compose up -d

For stop and delete: docker compose down